# Flash Flex Builder 4.6 Mobile Autocomplete

Tags: flash, sqlite, apache-flex, autocomplete

How can i do Autocomplete in Flash Flex Builder 4.6 Mobile app with SQLite contents. I am trying a lot and searched a lot in the internet but i couldn't able to find out valid answer.

I have done for desktop and web app but i am not able to do the Autocomplete for Mobile app.

I am able to create combo box but i want to do live search capability with mobile app. I want develop a auto search mobile app using Sqlite and Flash Flex Builder 4.6.

Please help me out !!!  Thanks in Advance ....

Comment: I recommend using the Flextras Mobile Autocomplete Component ( http://www.flextras.com/?event=ProductHome&productID=21 ), primarily because I built it.

Answer (score 0):

I have just completed Text input with suggestion Component for my Flex Web Project! I hope this can help you to reference
http://www.mediafire.com/view/9fzqlwv9b5y5i39/TextInputSuggesstion.mxml